# Problem in accessing hard drives by programs

Tags: external-hdd, accessibility

Until today I used Ubuntu 12.04, but after many suggestions to update to 14.04, I finally did so. However, I am no longer able to use artemis (a DNA sequence analysis program) when it needs to open files on external and internal extra hard drives. The program works normally when it has files on the main hard drive, but it looks like it has no "permission" to open the extra hard drives. Same happens from the terminal. When using a dir /media command, I see only two of my hard drives, yet I can easily get at my files at those drives through the file windows. Other programs, seaview, libroffice don't have this problem, but the NCBI BLAST program has neither access to files on the external drives.

Would much appreciate a solution, as I am getting pretty upset about this.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Jan Veenstra

Answer (score 0):

The mount location for user mountable drives has changed from 12.04 to 14.04:

`/media/drive` became `/media/$USER/drive`

Irritating at first, but makes sense.